# How to deploy Kind : V2 connection using Terraforms?

Tags: azure, terraform

Trying to deploy Queue Api connection with Kind V2 as have to get runtime URL which is only possible if its Kind : V2 right now its get deployed as V1

```
    resource "azurerm_api_connection" "azurequeuesconnect" {
  name                = "azurequeues"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  managed_api_id      = data.azurerm_managed_api.azurequeuesmp.id
  display_name        = "azurequeues"


  parameter_values = {
    "storageaccount" = data.azurerm_storage_account.blobStorageAccount.name
    "sharedkey" = data.azurerm_storage_account.blobStorageAccount.primary_access_key
  }
  tags = {
      "environment-id" = "testtag"
    }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is currently not possible. [See the github issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/16195)

I had a similar problem, and to workaround it I've used an ARM template and the 'azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment' terraform module.

Here is a reference:
https://github.com/microsoft/AzureTRE/blob/main/templates/shared_services/airlock_notifier/terraform/airlock_notifier.tf#L58

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using arm template with terraform template deployments

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).